# How to create a binary tree that also links grandparents to grandchildren?

Tags: algorithm, binary-tree

Is there is some algorithm to reach the grandchildren of a binary tree? Like the example?

[image]

In the picture, there are nodes linking grandparents to their grandchildren, whereas a normal binary tree only links children to parents.  What algorithm would one use to link to grandparents?

EDIT:
each node has an index and two values. 
[index] 
[value value];

What im trying to do:

```
index[3] and index[4] = value[0]; 
index[5] and index[6] = value[1]; 
index[7] and index[8] = value[2]; 
index[9] and index[10] = value[3]; 
.... ETC
```

Comment: What's wrong with simply following the child links down?

Comment: Hello, have you by chance tried anything yourself? Sounds like an interesting question, but I think some code would help make it fit better.  There's also [Computer Science SE](http://cs.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), which may be a better fit for questions about algorithms.

Comment: And what is this picture supposed to be showing???

Comment: I guess when building the binary tree, the child nodes could be built with links that point back to the grandparent. It seems like an operation that would be recursion within recursion.

Comment: @BobJarvis, it's a picture showing child nodes in a tree pointing back not just to their parents but to their grandparents.

Comment: What balancing algorithm are you planning on using? And what do you hope to gain by doing this?

Comment: @BobJarvis  Where did OP say that it has to be balanced?

Comment: @user3127065 - Wouldn't each node have to have six values?  Two for the children and four for the grandchildren?

Answer (score 6):

Typically you construct each node in a binary tree with two pointers: a left child pointer 'node.left' and a right child pointer node 'node.right'.  Then the four grandchildren of a node could be located with the expressions 'node.left.left', 'node.left.right', 'node.right.left', and 'node.right.right'.  These expressions will evaluate very quickly.

Accessing the grandchildren via this technique will make everything much simpler for the person who has to maintain your code, which might even be you ten months from now after you have had time to forget that you ever had this discussion.

If you insist on storing the grandchild pointers redundantly then you will need four additional pointers per node: 'node.leftleft', 'node.leftright', 'node.rightleft', and 'node.rightright'.

This feels like the very definition a bad idea.  Not only will the tree be big and clumsy, but every time you add or delete a node you will find yourself updating a metric barrowload of pointers.  In order to recoup the time you will spend debugging such a mess, you will have to use the program for about nine thousand years.

Answer (score 1):

0
  / \

1   2

/ \ / \

3 4 5 6

[0,1,2,3,4,5,6] Binary Tree as Array

left = 2n+1

right = 2n+2

left-left-grandChild = 2(2n+1)+1 => 4n+3

left-right-grandChild = 2(2n+1)+2 => 4n+4

right-left-grandChild = 2(2n+2)+1 => 4n+5

right-right-grandChild = 2(2n+2)+2 => 4n+6